# Visual Studio C++: Using static libraries produced by one project in another project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

I know next to nothing about using/linking libraries, so bear with me here. My lack of experience has made internet research fruitless so far.

I have one solution with three projects:

- *plus*, which contains plus.h and plus.cpp and compiles to a .lib
- *times*, which contains times.h and times.cpp and compiles to a .lib
- *main*, which needs to use the libraries compiled in *plus* and *times*.

The *plus* and *times* projects contain exactly what you'd expect in their header/source files - forward declarations and definitions of functions *plus* and *minus* that add/multiply two integers.

I want to use the functions *plus* and *times* in my *main* project. How can I do that? I guess that is to say, how do I get my *main* project to use the libraries compiled by projects *plus* and *times*?

Comment: You likely need to add the include paths (setting the Additional Include Directories setting for all configurations you will use) for both libraries in your main project and also link to both libraries (setting the linker -> input -> additional dependencies setting for each configuration).

Comment: Hint: `#pragma comment`, Add `#pragma comment( lib, "path to times.lib" )` and `#pragma comment( lib, "path to plus.lib" )` in main and include their headers you can use functions directly

Comment: For that you may have to specify different paths for release and debug.

Comment: In VS2019, right-click the main project in the Solution Explorer window > Add > Reference and tick the checkbox for the plus and times projects.

Answer (score 3):

###### Add plus and times to your main project as a reference:

`Right click on main project -> Add -> Reference... -> tick the plus and times projects`

###### Specify the paths to the header files of plus and times in your main project's additional include directories:

`Right click on main project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories`

### Read Also:

- Cherno: [Using Libraries in C++ (Static Linking)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=or1dAmUO8k0&t=730s)
- Microsoft: [Walkthrough: Create and use a static library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160)
- StackOverflow: [How static libraries work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677002/how-static-libraries-work-c-c/7677169)